# UIDatePicker with countDownTimer = 0 shows "0 hours 1 min"

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

```
var interval = enddate.timeIntervalSince(startdate)
interval = 0 // even if I set it explicitly to zero, it still doesn't work
self.datepicker.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer
self.datepicker.countDownDuration = interval
```

`startdate` and `enddate` are the same date, so the `interval=0` but just to double check I've set the interval=0 explicitly and it still doesn't work.

The UIDatePicker shows up in countDownTimer mode, but the ui elements are set to "0 hours, 1 min" instead of "0 hours, 0 min".

Why won't the date picker set to 0 mins to start?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Countdown Timer Picker can't be set to 0 hours and 0 minutes.
Think about it, will the user ever set a countdown for 0 time interval? It starts at 1 so that when the user starts the countdown there's always some amount of time to countdown to.

You can cross-check this in the system Clock app.

Comment: But I can manually change it to 0 mins, so the widget clearly supports setting to 0 hours and 0 minutes.

Comment: Are you sure? When I `UIDatePicker` try to set the value to 0 hours and 0 min it sort of bounces back to 1 min.

Comment: @KennyWyland: How did you do that? Could you please share the code?

Comment: In the Clock app on iOS 15 you can set timer to zero. It just won't let you start the timer. So it's possible. I think that might be some private API that they are not exposing to third party developers.